# How to calculate difference between row and row beneath, by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like the following

| name | time | medication | amount | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 6/10/22 7:22 | med1 | 1 | 97 |
| A | 6/10/22 16:15 | med1 | 5 | 97 |
| A | 6/11/22 6:15 | med2 | 15 | 97 |
| A | 6/11/22 15:44 | med2 | 31 | 97 |
| B | 5/20/22 6:30 | med1 | 10 | 93 |
| B | 5/20/22 13:21 | med1 | 12 | 93 |
| B | 5/21/22 8:43 | med2 | 16 | 93 |
| B | 5/21/22 14:35 | med2 | 24 | 93 |

For each entry, I want to calculate the amount * time duration * weight, grouped by both the name and medication. For time duration, I'm trying to calculate the difference between rows as a separate column, but the first value ends up as NA (as in row 1 = NA, row 2 = (row2  - row 1 ).

I'm hoping to get something like this:

| name | time | medication | amount | weight | time_diff | total_med |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 6/10/22 7:22 | med1 | 1 | 97 | 1 | 97 |
| A | 6/10/22 7:23 | med1 | 5 | 97 | 2 | 970 |
| A | 6/10/22 7:25 | med2 | 1 | 97 | 5 | 485 |
| A | 6/10/22 7:30 | med2 | 0 | 97 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 5/20/22 6:30 | med1 | 1 | 93 | 2 | 186 |
| B | 5/20/22 6:32 | med1 | 2 | 93 | 1 | 186 |
| B | 5/20/22 6:33 | med2 | 5 | 93 | 5 | 2325 |
| B | 5/21/22 6:38 | med2 | 0 | 93 | 0 | 0 |

but I keep getting

| name | time | medication | amount | weight | time_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 6/10/22 7:22 | med1 | 1 | 97 | NA |
| A | 6/10/22 7:23 | med1 | 5 | 97 | 1 |
| A | 6/10/22 7:25 | med2 | 1 | 97 | 2 |
| A | 6/10/22 7:30 | med2 | 0 | 97 | 5 |
| B | 5/20/22 6:30 | med1 | 1 | 93 | NA |
| B | 5/20/22 6:32 | med1 | 2 | 93 | 2 |
| B | 5/20/22 6:33 | med2 | 5 | 93 | 1 |
| B | 5/21/22 6:38 | med2 | 0 | 93 | 5 |

The code I am using is:

```r
df %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(time_diff=time-lag(time,default=first(time)))
```

How can I compute the column so that the first value is not NA, and the values are shifted up? And how can I combine that column with multiplication by weight and amount to get the total_med column?

Answer (score 0):

Using `diff`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate(time_diff = c(diff(as.POSIXct(time, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")), 0), 
        total_med = as.numeric(time_diff * amount * weight), .by = name)
  name         time medication amount weight time_diff total_med
1    A 6/10/22 7:22       med1      1     97    1 mins        97
2    A 6/10/22 7:23       med1      5     97    2 mins       970
3    A 6/10/22 7:25       med2      1     97    5 mins       485
4    A 6/10/22 7:30       med2      0     97    0 mins         0
5    B 5/20/22 6:30       med1      1     93    2 mins       186
6    B 5/20/22 6:32       med1      2     93    1 mins       186
7    B 5/20/22 6:33       med2      5     93 1445 mins    671925
8    B 5/21/22 6:38       med2      0     93    0 mins         0
```

or alternatively take a look at `dplyr::lead`

Comment: Why not offer a link to the multiple duplicates?